# IPad videos don't play after multiple runs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, media-player

I'm working on an IPad application (iOS 3.2) that plays a couple of videos using the MediaPlayer framework. After running the app for a while videos don't play anymore. The video is loaded, meaning i can buffer through it but it's started in pause mode and cannot be set to played. Each time i press play it pauses again. After restarting the device videos behave normal again.
Does anyone have any idea why this strange behavior happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution that worked for me. If i set the MPMoviePlayerController's useApplicationAudioSession to NO then videos play normally.